# Code displays intended output but is marked wrong. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

Learning Javascript on codeacademy.  Usually they allow you to use a different method so long as it prints the right thing, but I can't discern why it's not accepting my answer on this one.

My code:

```
function displayStaffStatus() {
  availableAirplanes.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(`${element.name} meets staff requirements: ${meetsStaffRequirements(element.availableStaff,flightRequirements.requiredStaff)}`)   
  })
};
```

The code they suggest (not using interpolation):

```
function displayStaffStatus() {
  availableAirplanes.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element.name + ' meets staff requirements: ' + meetsStaffRequirements(element.availableStaff, flightRequirements.requiredStaff) );
  });
}
```

code prints out

```
AeroJet meets staff requirements: true
SkyJet meets staff requirements: false
```

when they say they're looking for:

```
(element name) + ' meets staff requirements: ' + (true/false)
```

Comment: I suggest you produce the output they require. After all, isn't that the point? Otherwise recommend using the feedback tool to tell them either the requested output is incorrect or the suggested solution is incorrect. FYI there is obviously  nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Ah strange, as I'm learning to program I'm trying to make sure I understand concepts, and most times so long as the right thing prints to console, it's marked right. I'm trying to improve my knowledge by answering it with a different method so that I know I've memorized the syntax. It would see there are bugs with codeacademy. Thank you!